# AngularJs, SSO with get files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-sign-on, restful-authentication

I'm developing an web with AngularJs and a restful backend. The application requires secure login (all, good, this has been done with a token that expires every X minutes) but we have problems with images and files. When the user tries to download an images/file must be done with get and not $http as AJAX does not allow file manipulation, so when the user tries to download a file, we get session expired error that we cannot handle with Angular.

Any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: Should a cookie be set in the browser?

Comment: the cookie will expire every X minutes. Then what we do is request a new valid cookie... but we cannot do that when the request is a direct get request.

Comment: You are asking to troubleshoot a server configuration we know nothing about. You haven't explained why cookies in get requests won't work either

Comment: Server configuration is irrelevant really. We have a RESTful API that uses a cookie token that expires every X minutes. When we make a normal call using AngularJS, we can check if we get an error and then request a new cookie... but doing a get request, if the cookie has expired we'll get an error 419 (or whatever code, we can change that) but we won't be able to handle the error as it's a direct GET call.